# Get rows from dataframe based on many columns and values

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a very simple recreation although the real DF has many more columns

My dataframe:

```
    length  width  height  age
0        1      5       8   12
1        1      5       8   12
2        1      5       8   21
3        1      5       8   15
4        1      5       8   15
5        1      6       9   12
6        2      6       9   32
7        2      6       9   32
8        2      6       7   98
9        3      4       7   12
10       3      4       7   54
11       3      4       7   21
```

I want to get the rows where `width == 6` **and** `age ==32`.

Easy enough:

```
d[(d['width']==6) & (d['age']==32)]

   length  width  height  age
6       2      6       9   32
7       2      6       9   32
```

Is there a way to automate this even more? Let's say I have a list of columns and values. In this case it's still only two columns/values, but I'm thinking about dealing with 15 or more:

```
cols = ['width','age']
vals = [6,32]
```

Now to build an empty dataframe and update the rows with `append`:

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame()

for col,val in zip(cols,vals):


    if df_temp.empty:

        df_temp = df[df[col]==val]

    else:

        df_temp.append(df[df[col]==val])


   length  width  height  age
5       1      6       9   12
6       2      6       9   32
7       2      6       9   32
8       2      6       7   98
```

What this does is equivalent to using the `or` symbol `|`:

```
d[(d['width']==6) | (d['age']==32)]
```

How can I automate this so it is `AND` rather than `or` ?

I've tried something completely outrageous but it doesn't work, it's still seems to be equivalent to `|` instead of `&`.

```
[d[(d[col]==val) & (d[col]==val)] for col, val in zip(cols,vals)][0]

   length  width  height  age
5       1      6       9   12
6       2      6       9   32
7       2      6       9   32
8       2      6       7   98
```

My reproducible dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({'length': pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=12, step=1)), 'width': pd.Series([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=12, step=1)), 'height': pd.Series([8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 7, 7],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=12, step=1)), 'age': pd.Series([12, 12, 21, 15, 15, 12, 32, 32, 98, 12, 54, 21],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=12, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=12, step=1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simplify this by working with the underlying numpy arrays here:

```
df[(df[cols].values == vals).all(1)] 

     length  width  height  age
6       2      6       9   32
7       2      6       9   32
```

Comment: Thank you. I've read the `all()` documentation but still not sure what is happening here. What exactly is it doing? It's checking for `nan` values? And returns false if a value along the rows is `nan` ?

Comment: `all` will return a true if all values from the same iterable are True, otherwise False. Here it is doing so along the first axis @scool [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) are the docs

Comment: It works for my test dataset above, but unfortunately it does not work in the "real world". It is returning an empty dataframe.

Comment: I just removed the `.values` and now it's working. `df[(df[cols] == vals).all(1)]`

Comment: Well we need to know what the "real world" is to get it to work :) Glad its working now @scool

Comment: @yatu Will the equality not work without the `.values`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way using [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html);

```
df[df.eq(df.assign(**dict(zip(cols,vals)))).loc[:,cols].all(1)]
```

---

```
   length  width  height  age
6       2      6       9   32
7       2      6       9   32
```